# Formula to find an angle of point on a coordinate plane

Tags: computer-science, planar-graphs, plane-geometry, angle

Given a plane and an arbitrary (x,y) point, is there a succinct formula to find the angle of that point against the positive y-axis? For example, pictured below the green point is 0 degrees, blue 45 degrees, red 180 degrees, and a point such as the pink one is **315 degrees**, not 45 degrees from the the positive y-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that will help give you what you want is the “[atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)” function. The way it measures the angle is counter-clockwise from the horizontal axis, and it gives an answer between $-180^\circ$ and $180^\circ$. Since you want to measure the angle clockwise, you need to add a minus sign, and since you want answers between $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$, you need to adjust for that also. Can you figure out a nice formula for just what you want now?